# Private accept for a BehaviorRelay RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift

I am trying to get deeper on RxSwift and I was wondering If there is a way to "private accept" value on a BehaviorRelay object in RxSwift. So my ClassA has a BehaviorRelay that only ClassA can set but, for instance, ClassB can subscribe.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class A {
    var property: Observable<Int> {
        return _property.asObservable()
    }
    private let _property = PublishSubject<Int>()
}
```

The above is a pretty standard way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about that but I wanted to know, as you said, the standard way.